# Having trouble calling a variable in two functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have a calculator that takes two inputs and runs three functions. The first function uses both inputs and the second takes the return from the first function and one of the inputs. the third function takes the return from the first two and compares them.

I am having trouble putting the return from the first function into the second function.

```
//the user inputs two values (priorLoan,newLoan)

//this function makes the first calculation and that value is then further calculated in the next function

function refiCalc (priorLoan,newLoan) {

if (priorLoan>newLoan){
    if (newLoan <= 100000) {
        return Math.ceil(newLoan/1000)*2.5
    }else if (newLoan <= 500000) {
        return 250+Math.ceil((newLoan-100000)/1000)*2.25
    }else if (newLoan <= 2000000) {
        return 1150+Math.ceil((newLoan-500000)/1000)*2
    }else{ return 4150+Math.ceil((newLoan-2000000)/1000)*1.5

}
    }else{
    if (priorLoan <= 100000) {
        return Math.ceil(priorLoan/1000)*2.5
    }else if (priorLoan <= 500000) {
        return 250+Math.ceil((priorLoan-100000)/1000)*2.25
    }else if (priorLoan <= 2000000) {
        return 1150+Math.ceil((priorLoan-500000)/1000)*2
    }else{ return 4150+Math.ceil((priorLoan-2000000)/1000)*1.5
}
}
}



//this part takes the value from the refiCalc and the value from the newLoan

function lenderRefiblend (newLoan,refiCalculator){
if (refiCalculator<0){

    if (newLoan<=100000){
            return Math.ceil(newLoan/1000)*5;
    }else if((newLoan-100000)<=500000){
        return 500+Math.ceil((newLoan-100000)/1000)*3.95;
    }else if ((newLoan-500000)<=2000000) {
        return 2080+Math.ceil((newLoan-500000)/1000)*2.65;
    }else{
        return 6055+Math.ceil((newLoan-2000000)/1000)*2;
    }

}else if (refiCalculator<=250){
    if ((refiCalculator/2.5)>0){
        if ((newLoan-100000)>0){
            return (100-(refiCalculator/2.5)*5)
        }else{
            return ((Math.ceil(newLoan/1000))-(refiCalculator/2.5))*5
        }
    }else{
        return Math.ceil(newLoan/1000)*5
    }

}else if (refiCalculator<=1150){
    if (((refiCalculator-250)/2.25)>0){
        if ((newLoan-500000)>0){
            return (400-((refiCalculator-250)/2.25)*3.95)
        }else{
            return ((Math.ceil((newLoan-100000)/1000))-((refiCalculator-250)/2.25))*3.95
        }
    }else{
        return Math.ceil(newLoan/1000)*3.95
    }

}else if (refiCalculator<=4150){
    if (((refiCalculator-1150)/2)>0){
        if ((newLoan-2000000)>0){
            return (1500-((refiCalculator-1150)/2)*2.65)
        }else{
            return ((Math.ceil((newLoan-500000)/1000))-((refiCalculator-1150)/2))*2.65
        }
    }else{
        return Math.ceil(newLoan/1000)*2.65
    }

}else{
     return ((Math.ceil((newLoan-2000000)/1000))-((refiCalculator-4150)/1.5))*2
}
}

//in the end i want to combine the total of reficalc and lenderRefiblend

function refiPremium (refi,blend) {
if ((refi+blend)<200) {
    return 200
}else{
    return refi+blend
}
}

//what is stumping me is how I would go about putting the refiCalc return into my lenderRefiblend 

function updateOutput(form){

    var newLoan = parseInt(form.elements["new_loan_amount"].value);
    var priorLoan = parseInt(form.elements ["prior_loan_amount"].value);

    form.elements["premium_rate"].value = refiPremium(refiCalc(priorLoan,newLoan),lenderRefiblend(newLoan,refiCalc));
}

//--></script>


<form id="standardPremiumcalc">
    <input name= "new_loan_amount" type="number" value="0">
    <input name= "prior_loan_amount" type="number" value="0">
    <input type=button name=calcnun value="Calculate" onClick="javascript:updateOutput(this.form)">
    Value is: <input name= "premium_rate" type="number">
</form>
```

Comment: Just so you know, you don't 'call' variables, you 'call' functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extra variables for this...

```
var refiCalcResult = refiCalc(priorLoan, newLoan),
    lenderRefiblendResult = lenderRefiblend(newLoan, refiCalcResult),
    refiPremiumResult = refiPremium(refiCalcResult, lenderRefiblendResult);
```